# Snapping points to lines in QGIS/PostGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, sql, snapping

I'm attempting to snap approximately 900 points to a line table.

I've tried recreating what I have found from a couple of PostGIS answers but not having much luck. To test, I've created two simplified tables; one for points (ptest) and one for the lines (ltest). The test tables only consist of an ID column.

```
CREATE TABLE line_attribute_point AS 
    SELECT 
        distinct on (ltest.id) ltest.*,
        ST_ClosestPoint(ltest.geom, ptest.geom) as snapped_point 
    FROM
        ltest,ptest
    ORDER BY ST_Distance(ltest.geom, ptest.geom);
```

The main error seems to be the ORDER BY.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to do? For every point, find a closest line and snap point onto it?

Comment: yes, find closest segment (not vertex) and snap to it. All points are within about 50m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use a function in the order by clause, because you are tempting to sort a table with a column that not exists. 
Try this

```
CREATE TABLE line_attribute_point AS 
    SELECT 
        distinct on (ltest.id) ltest.*,
        ST_Distance(ltest.geom, ptest.geom) as distance,
        ST_ClosestPoint(ltest.geom, ptest.geom) as snapped_point 
    FROM
        ltest,ptest
    ORDER BY distance;
```

But you don't have what you want with this query. (but it works)

I suggest something like this (not tested):

```
--create a table with id and distance
CREATE TABLE line_attribute_point AS 
    SELECT 
        ltest.id as lid,
        ptest.id as pid,
        ST_Distance(ltest.geom, ptest.geom)::double precision as distance
    FROM
        ltest,ptest
    ORDER BY distance;

--because the same point could be near to one or more lines take only the point whit the closest line
CREATE TABLE line_attribute_point_min AS
     SELECT 
       pid, 
       min(distance) as min_distance
     FROM 
       line_attribute_point
     GROUP BY 
       pid;

--re-assign the line id to point id

ALTER TABLE line_attribute_point_min ADD COLUMN lid integer;

UPDATE line_attribute_point_min as lap_min 
   SET lid=lap.lid
   FROM line_attribute_point as lap
   WHERE lap_min.pid=lap.pid AND lap_min.min_distance=lap.distance;

--create the geometry column and after that you can use this table for update the geometry of ptest and have the point snapped to lines

ALTER TABLE line_attribute_point_min ADD COLUMN geom geometry(Point, SRID);

UPDATE line_attribute_point_min as lap_min
   SET geom=ST_ClosestPoint(ltest.geom, ptest.geom)
   FROM ltest, ptest
   WHERE ltest.id=lap_min.lid AND ptest.id=lap_min.pid;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. Error with the "AS" in  SET geom=ST_ClosestPoint(ltest.geom, ptest.geom) AS geom

Comment: sorry, query updated.

Comment: Sorry seems to have an issue with missing FROM-clause entry for table "lapmin" in WHERE lapmin.pid=lap.pid AND lapmin.min_distance=lap.dist...

Comment: its lap_min not lapmin, updated

Comment: thanks, getting there I think. It seems to have an issue with the SRID - I removed it and it ran without error, however created an empty table? I manually set SRID to 27700 when adding to the QGIS canvas.

Comment: geometry(Point, SRID)---> geometry(Point, 27700) try this. Open the table and look if it has rows (all the tables). Be sure your two layers ltest, ptest are in the same SRID

Comment: Yeah both are the same SRID, The output table is empty unfortunately apart from the defined column headings. FYI - the ltest table has 1 entry, the ptest table has 6

Comment: table line_attribute_point is empty? That's not possible... there is something wrong in your layers, but I can't say what.

Comment: Ah seems to be working now! No idea what was different from the other day. I started from scratch again and used your query above and it seems to be working perfectly. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

Does that select do what you want?

```
SELECT 
    ST_ClosestPoint(close_line.geom, ptest.geom)
FROM 
    (
     SELECT 
         ltest.geom AS geom
         FROM ltest, ptest
         ORDER BY 
             ST_Distance(ltest.geom, ptest.geom)
         LIMIT 1
    ) close_line,
    ptest
;
```

Comment: it's having issue with the lines table - is this what you meant to select from?

Comment: fixed it, `select from ltest` in nested query, as close_line

Comment: I changed FROM ltest to FROM ltest, ptest as was getting an error on the ptest.geom in ORDER BY. I presume I need to create the close_line table to begin with?